# How can one animate position using CSS -webkit-animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload, transition

I want to make an image go from poitn a to point b. I can animate the blur, and scale smoothly but the position is not working. It doesn't flow as it should. I have tried it with translatex and translate y and it doesn't seem to respond. Can someone please give me a hand. Here is my code.

```css
body {overflow:hidden;
margin: 0;}
  #bird {position: relative;
   -webkit-animation: birdfly 5s linear infinite;
     animation: birdfly 5s linear infinite;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes birdfly {
  0% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
    left:110px; top:200px;
  }
  
  }
   100% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8, 1.8);
    left:400px; top:600px;
  }
}

@keyframes birdfly {
  0% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
    left:110px; top:200px;
  }
  
  }
   100% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8, 1.8);
    left:400px; top:600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Animated image</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="bird">
   <img src="http://i556.photobucket.com/albums/ss3/t_wangrung/Bird/ibon.gif">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your source.

```css
body {overflow:hidden;
margin: 0;}
  #bird {position: relative;
   -webkit-animation: birdfly 5s linear infinite;
     animation: birdfly 5s linear infinite;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes birdfly {
  0% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 200px);
    transform: translate(110px, 200px);
  }
  
  }
   100% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8, 1.8);
    -webkit-transform: translate(400px, 600px);
    transform: translate(400px, 600px);
  }
}

@keyframes birdfly {
  0% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 200px);
    transform: translate(110px, 200px);
  }
  
  }
   100% { 
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8, 1.8);
    -webkit-transform: translate(400px, 600px);
    transform: translate(400px, 600px);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Animated image</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="bird">
   <img src="http://i556.photobucket.com/albums/ss3/t_wangrung/Bird/ibon.gif">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to use the -webkit-transform: translate(translateX, translateY) property.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$("img").animate({
    left: newXValue,
    top: newYValue
});
```

For more details see: http://api.jquery.com/animate/