# Add animation when elements are moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning Javascript and jQuery now, and I ran into the following problem:
I have a script that adds boxes to the screen, and they always stay in center. Lets assume I have added one box and it is horizontally aligned in center. Now when I add another box, the first box will automatically move a little to the left, so that they both are aligned in the center. In my case this movement to the left is instantaneous. How can I add animation to it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sort.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="brain.js"></script>

<Title>Sorting</Title>

</head>
<body>


<input type="button" id="done" value="Done"></input>
<input type="text" id="entry"></input>


<div id="array">
<!-- Items are added here! -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    //Done button clicked
    $("#done").on('click', function(){
        //Action code goes here!
        getNumbers();

        //Hide all the numbers 
        $(".boxed:not(.onScreen)").css({
            display : 'none'
        });
        $('.boxed').fadeIn(1000).addClass("onScreen");


    });


    $("#entry").on("keyup", function(){

        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#done").click();
        }

    });



});

//For every Number in the array wil create a box with two classes: "onScreen and boxed"
function addElement(numbers){
    console.log("addElement " + numbers);

    for(var i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){

        if (isNumber(numbers[i])){
            console.log("Creating element " + numbers[i]);
            var para = document.createElement("div");
            para.className = "boxed";
            var node = document.createTextNode(numbers[i]);
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("array");
            element.appendChild(para);



        }
    }

}

//Will get the numbers from the input. 
//Will pass an array of elements to addElement
function getNumbers(){
    console.log("getNumbers");
    var elements = document.getElementById("entry").value;
    document.getElementById("entry").value = "";
    var numbers = elements.split(",");
    console.log(numbers);
    addElement(numbers);

}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #DDE9E9;
}

.boxed{
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;

    border: 0px solid #232525;
    border-radius: 15px;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 25px;

    text-align: center;

    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888888;


    display: inline-block;
}

.onScreen{



}


#array{

    text-align: center;

}
```

Adding transition to an array did not work. For some reason it also appears blurred in chrome developer window

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one animate position using CSS -webkit-animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644962/how-can-one-animate-position-using-css-webkit-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this possible with your code took a bunch edits but basically, I've added a wrapper around each box (so that the width can be set to 0), then I applied the box-shadow and margins to the containers. Next set width to 0  > Insert into document > set width to natural (I had to do a check by moving the box outside of the document to get the width then set to 0 and move back into the document).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Done button clicked
  $("#done").on('click', function() {
    //Action code goes here!
    getNumbers();
  });
  $("#entry").on("keyup", function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("#done").click();
    }
  });
});
//For every Number in the array wil create a box with two classes: "onScreen and boxed"
function addElement(numbers) {
    console.log("addElement " + numbers);
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (isNumber(numbers[i])) {
        console.log("Creating element " + numbers[i]);
        var wrap = document.createElement("div");
        wrap.className = "boxed";
        var para = document.createElement("div");
        para.className = "boxed-inner";
        var node = document.createTextNode(numbers[i]);
        para.appendChild(node);
        wrap.appendChild(para);
        wrap.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        wrap.style.left = '-100%';
        var element = document.getElementById("array");
        element.appendChild(wrap);
        var width = window.getComputedStyle(wrap, null).width;
        wrap.style.width = '0px';
        wrap.style.left = '0px';
        wrap.style.visibility = 'initial';
        wrap.style.opacity = '0';
        $(wrap).animate({
          'opacity': '1',
          'width': width
        });
      }
    }
  }
  //Will get the numbers from the input. 
  //Will pass an array of elements to addElement

function getNumbers() {
  console.log("getNumbers");
  var elements = document.getElementById("entry").value;
  document.getElementById("entry").value = "";
  var numbers = elements.split(",");
  console.log(numbers);
  addElement(numbers);

}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDE9E9;
}
.boxed {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888888;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.boxed-inner {
  border: 0px solid #232525;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888888;
  display: inline-block;
}
#array {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- for demo only -->
<input type="button" id="done" value="Done">
<input type="text" id="entry">
<div id="array">
  <!-- Items are added here! -->
</div>
```

Comment: It did not help, I have added the comment at the end of the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to transition the width of the added box. Start the newly added box with width 0 and animate/transition it to be full width.

Answer (score 0):

To build on humble.rumble.6x3's answer, you can add the transition value, add your selectors, timing, and easing. Then, you can use javascript to set the value of anything and animate it. Just note that CSS3 animations are only supported with newer browsers.